# How to display Google Fit data sets in a graph?

Tags: android, graph, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm new in coding so please be specific with the answer if possible, because I might not fully understand the obvious things:)

I want to display a set of data that I get from Google Fit API in a graph (don't have any one in mind so You can propose a simple one)
I'm using Android Studio 2.2

I got the datasets fromo the last 7 days in logs but dont know what to do with it later on.

```
 private static void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
        DateFormat dateFormat = getTimeInstance();
        TextView textView;

        for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
            Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
            Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Value val = dp.getValue(field);
                String fieldName = field.getName();
                Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() +
                        " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
            }
        }
    }
```

Logs put out datasets for 7 days (one dataset below):

```
I/BasicHistoryApi:Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: 7
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data returned for Data type: com.google.step_count.delta
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data point:
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Type: com.google.step_count.delta
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Start: 12:01:46
I/BasicHistoryApi:  End: 11:47:10
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Field: steps Value: 6844
```

I hope that You get my intensions.
Thank You very much in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these library for show data in Graphical way.

https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Graph.md

just Read the Documentation and follow the steps.